# Override responsive queries for IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, responsive-design

I am modifying another developer's files and they had the following jquery set up to ensure that the website doesn't respond to queries in IE8 and it just shows the 960 width style. It is not working anymore though and I can't figure out why.

```
function getWidth() {
if ($("html").hasClass("lt-ie9"))  { return 960; }
return jQuery(window).width();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are the media queries in a separate CSS file? If so, you can just wrap conditional tags around the CSS link.

```
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mediaqueries.css">
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Comment: It's actually a Drupal site and the css files are pulled from the themename.info file so I can't use that option.

Comment: It doesn't matter, [this will work](https://www.drupal.org/node/1031344) in Drupal.

Comment: My pleasure, let me know if you run into any issues. Make sure to clear your cache any time you update the .info file by going to `Administration > Appearance`